# Accessing object property of a component in a template doesn't show that object's properties

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I have an interface defined as follows

```
export interface I18nStrings {
    header: any;
    footer: any;
    sideNav: any;
}
```

In a component I have defined a property

```
strings: I18nStrings;
```

When I type `this.strings.` in the component, my IDE shows me the properties available on `this.strings`.

I would like that the same thing happens when I type `{{strings.` in the component's html template.

Is this possible? If it is, how can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are working in VS code, then install extension "Angular Language Service". It serves the purpose you are looking for

Comment: And don't forget to put the `@angular/language-service` as devDependencies on _package.json_ file